# Protobuf multiple object serialization order?

Tags: protobuf-net

I am building a socket Server - Client application and I am using protobuf-net to serialize/deserialize the data sent from one to the other. Right now I am sending a single object and on the receptor, based on the header of the packet I know what I suppose to receive and deserialize. I was wondering if will be possible to send multiple objects as object[] with different types on it, serialize and deserialize independent of the order of the objects on the array? I assume this means that each object on the array should have a type identifier someway serialized so on deserialize I know which object it is. an additionally, a variable identifier (like the variable name) so multiple objects with the same type can be differienciated.

I assume that the easiest way is to always wrap my data in a single object with all my data as properties. Just wondering if this was possible some way as will make my code much easier not to have to create all these wrapper classes.

Answer (score 1):

`object` is pretty awkward because the engine has no way of knowing what you intend. There *is* some dynamic type stuff baked into protobuf-net, which embeds the type AQN, but frankly that's a huge hack. By far your best bet is to restrict yourself to some limited inheritance model. For example:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Foo)]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Bar)]
public class MessageBase {}
```

with

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo : MessageBase {}
```

(and similarly `Bar`)

Then send a `MessageBase[]` and use `Deserialize` (or `DeserializeWithLengthPrefix`) specifying `<MessageBase>`. Each message will be sent and retreived as the correct type, allow either polymorphism or the new `switch` pattern-matching to be used to route incoming messages, and there is no ambiguity.

Behind the scenes, this is implemented like (in .proto terms):

```
message MessageBase {
    oneof ActualType {
        Foo foo = 1;
        Bar bar = 2;
    }
}
message Foo {}
message Bar {}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, I am trying to build a framework for my send/receive similar to web development where the parameters in the Controller action doesn't need to have an specific order. So my receptor have an `Action(int userId, ComplexObj data, int age)` to be able to send from the caller `PacketSend(actionRoute, params object[] objs)` and then on the receptor to deserialize these parameters and assign them to the method via `MethodInfo.Invoke()` I am not sure if this is achievable with protobuf as on deserialize I will not be able to diferenciate userId from age if the caller change the order.

Comment: So I think my only option with protobuf is to create a single wrapper class where these parameters are properties, and change my PacketSend(actionRoute, object obj) serialize it there and use the wrapper class for deserialization on the receiver. Basically restricting myself to 1 parameter per Action.

Comment: @Nauzet that is essentially how protobuf defines services, so... that's probably the way to go